# unable to start tomcat 8 in kepler eclipse adding resource tags in server.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I am getting the below exception when trying to start tomcat 8 from kepler eclipse after adding a project. I could run the same project in lomboz eclipse with tomcat 5.5.

I am still using the same jar files which I used previously in lomboz eclipse.

Can anyone please help me to fix this up.

```
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;.
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8086"]
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 839 ms
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.8
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/esample]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/esample]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LConfiguration;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5069)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Configuration
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1180)
        ... 20 more

    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8007]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8086"]
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8086"]
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
    Sep 11, 2014 3:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
    WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/esample]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
    javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
        at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5398)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:272)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1013)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1013)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:603)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: I am able to build the project successfully but running into errors when trying to run tomcat. Please note that we have upgraded from Jdk 1.5 to 1.7 and Tomcat 5.5 to 8. These projects were running fine in previous setups (jdk1.5 & tomcat 5.5). Tomcat runs fine if I remove the resource tags of the projects which have issues. Throws the mentioned errors when adding the resource tags for the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error can happen when your jar files has not been exported with your web archive,
 you can follow below steps .

```
Right click the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
```

Comment: Hi, I have added all the jar files from Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars. Still it is not working.

Comment: @Lettisha Try coping commons-logging.jar file to WEB-INF/lib folder.You can download it from here[link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi),and i want to know about is it Maven Project?

Comment: Hey I already have commons-logging.jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. And ours is not a Maven Project. This project was working fine in jdk 1.5 and tomcat 5.5. We are getting these exception after upgrading to jdk 1.7 and tomcat 8

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't include a library in your project.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LConfiguration;
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Configuration
```

You are missing jar file. Try to include in under WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Tried downloading commons-configuration-1.7.jar and included it in WEB-INF/lib folder. Still no luck :(

Comment: just a dirty suggestion, reinstall tomcat again. Somehow it doesn't install correctly.

Comment: But its working fine with other projects. I have problem running only 2 projects. rest all my projects are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue caused by older version of java so try with java 1.7 or java 1.8

Also try

1. Check JAVA_HOME in system variable
2. Check Installed JRE in eclipse: window >> preferences >> Java >> Installed JRE and point the right jdk or jre
3. Check java tomcat server should match with Java version type(32bit or 64 bit)

Comment: Hello Sasi, I have checked the system variables and JRE in eclipse. They all look good.  Actually I am able to run other projects. Problem is with only 2 projects.